# gantt chart issues

Tags: errors, titles, pgfgantt, charts, gantt

I have two problems:

- The title of the `gantt` chart contains dotted lines that I don't want.
- Is it possible to also provide the progression of the taskbars? If so, how would that be done? ( please see second figure below for more clarification, the picture is taken from the pgfgantt package)

`gantt` package used can be found [here](http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=05Misc:A_LaTeX_package_for_gantt_plots)

All help is highly appreciated.

Greetings

```
    \documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{gantt}

\newcommand{\defcolor}{blue}

\begin{document}

    \begin{gantt}[drawledgerline=true]{18}{24}
        % vertical, horizontal 'boxes'
    \begin{ganttitle}  % First title: Year 
        \numtitle{2019}{1}{2019}{24}  
        % start, label, width 
    \end{ganttitle}

    \begin{ganttitle} % Second title: Months
        \titleelement{Feb}{4}
        \titleelement{Mar}{4}
        \titleelement{Apr}{4}
        \titleelement{May}{4}
        \titleelement{Jun}{4}
        \titleelement{Jul}{4}
    \end{ganttitle}

    \begin{ganttitle} % Third title: Weeks
        \numtitle{6}{1}{29}{1}
        % start, skip, end, width       
    \end{ganttitle}

    %---------------------------------------
     \ganttmilestone{Task A}{0} % Milestone: Label, position
    %---------------------------------------


    %--------------------------------------- 
    %   Task B
    %---------------------------------------
    \ganttgroup{Task B}{0}{6} % start, width 
    %
    \ganttbar[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{0}{1}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{1}{1}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{1}{4}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{3}{3}
    %
    \ganttmilestonecon{Task B}{6}
    %---------------------------------------


    %--------------------------------------- 
    %   Task C
    %---------------------------------------
    \ganttgroup{Task C}{6}{15} % start, width 
    %
    \ganttbar[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{6}{2}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{8}{8}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{15}{3}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{16}{4}
    %
    \ganttmilestonecon{Task C}{20}
    %
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{20}{1}
    %
    \ganttmilestonecon{Task C}{21}
    %---------------------------------------
    \end{gantt}

\end{document}
```

[image: gantt package]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  It is best to ask just one specific question in a given posting; your posting asks two.  The second one about progression is not so clear.  I suggest you edit your posting removing that part, and think about how to formulate a second positing for a specific version of that problem.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I have added a new picture to clarify the second question. I know that the progressbar is possible within pgfgantt. But I'd like to stick to my format/design and include the progress if possible. I tried within pgfgantt, but I couldn't get the same out, unfortunately.

Comment: Just so that I understand the second question better, for any task you want to partially fill the bar with a completion percentage and also add a label?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, you got it totally right. I'd like to show the progress in terms precentages and filling for each particular task if possible.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, I started a new question to keep in line with the required set-up of questioning.

Answer (score 1):

### Getting rid of the spurious dotted lines

Here's an answer to the first question. This is IMO the result of a bug in the package. In the command that draws the vertical lines, the `y` coordinate is incorrectly specified.  This can be patched using the `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{gantt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\gantt}{-0.5}{-1.5}{}{}

\newcommand{\defcolor}{blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{gantt}[drawledgerline=true]{18}{24}
    % vertical, horizontal 'boxes'
\begin{ganttitle}  % First title: Year 
    \numtitle{2019}{1}{2019}{24}  
    % start, label, width 
\end{ganttitle}

\begin{ganttitle} % Second title: Months
    \titleelement{Feb}{4}
    \titleelement{Mar}{4}
    \titleelement{Apr}{4}
    \titleelement{May}{4}
    \titleelement{Jun}{4}
    \titleelement{Jul}{4}
\end{ganttitle}

\begin{ganttitle} % Third title: Weeks
    \numtitle{6}{1}{29}{1}
    % start, skip, end, width       
\end{ganttitle}

%---------------------------------------
 \ganttmilestone{Task A}{0} % Milestone: Label, position
%---------------------------------------


%--------------------------------------- 
%   Task B
%---------------------------------------
\ganttgroup{Task B}{0}{6} % start, width 
%
\ganttbar[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{0}{1}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{1}{1}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{1}{4}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{3}{3}
%
\ganttmilestonecon{Task B}{6}
%---------------------------------------


%--------------------------------------- 
%   Task C
%---------------------------------------
\ganttgroup{Task C}{6}{15} % start, width 
%
\ganttbar[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{6}{2}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{8}{8}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{15}{3}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{16}{4}
%
\ganttmilestonecon{Task C}{20}
%
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{20}{1}
%
\ganttmilestonecon{Task C}{21}
%---------------------------------------
\end{gantt}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Adding completion bars

Here's an answer to the second question.  I've added a `percent` key to the `\ganttbar` commands which give the percentage completion (values range from 0-1).  The default is 1. I've also added a key for the position of the completion label. This defaults to `right` but can be specified also as `left`. Finally there's a key `plabeltext` which defines the string printed out after the completion amount.  It is preset to `% Complete` but can be changed using `\presetkeys{ganttbarx}{plabeltext=<text>}{}`.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{gantt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\gantt}{-0.5}{-1.5}{}{}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\gantttmpc}
\newlength{\ganttbarpercentage}
\define@key{ganttbarx}{percent}{\def\ganttbarpercent{#1}\pgfmathparse{int(round(\ganttbarpercent*100))}\let\ganttbarpercentage\pgfmathresult}
\define@key{ganttbarx}{percentpos}{\def\@tmp{left}\def\ganttbarpercentpos{#1}\ifx\ganttbarpercentpos\@tmp\def\ganttbarpercentanchor{\gantttmpa}\else\def\ganttbarpercentanchor{\gantttmpb}\fi}
\define@key{ganttbarx}{plabeltext}{\def\ganttbarplabeltext{#1}}
\presetkeys{ganttbarx}{pattern=north west lines,color=black,percent=1,plabeltext={\% Complete},percentpos=right}{}

\renewcommand{\ganttbar}[4][]{
  \setlength{\gantttmpa}{#3\ganttunitlength}
  \setlength{\gantttmpb}{#4\ganttunitlength}
  \setlength{\gantttmpc}{#4\ganttunitlength}
  \setlength{\gantttmpb}{\gantttmpa+\gantttmpb}

  \ifKV@ganttx@drawledgerline
    \draw[dotted] (0,\value{ganttnum}-0.2) -- (\value{ganttwidth}*\ganttunitlength,\value{ganttnum}-0.2);
  \fi
  \node at (0,\value{ganttnum}) [anchor=base east] {%
        \ganttfontsize #2%
  };
  \setkeys{ganttbarx}{#1}{%
  \setlength{\gantttmpc}{\gantttmpa+\ganttbarpercent\gantttmpc}
  \draw[] (\gantttmpa,\value{ganttnum}+0.1) rectangle (\gantttmpb,\value{ganttnum}+0.5);
  \node at (\ganttbarpercentanchor,\value{ganttnum}+0.25) [\ganttbarpercentpos=.5\ganttunitlength] {\ganttbarpercentage\ganttbarplabeltext};
  \fill[pattern=\ganttbarpattern,pattern color=\ganttbarcolor] (\gantttmpa,\value{ganttnum}+0.1) rectangle (\gantttmpc,\value{ganttnum}+0.5);
  }     
  \setlength{\ganttlastx}{\gantttmpb}
  \addtocounter{ganttnum}{-1}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\defcolor}{blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{gantt}[drawledgerline=true]{18}{24}
    % vertical, horizontal 'boxes'
\begin{ganttitle}  % First title: Year 
    \numtitle{2019}{1}{2019}{24}  
    % start, label, width 
\end{ganttitle}

\begin{ganttitle} % Second title: Months
    \titleelement{Feb}{4}
    \titleelement{Mar}{4}
    \titleelement{Apr}{4}
    \titleelement{May}{4}
    \titleelement{Jun}{4}
    \titleelement{Jul}{4}
\end{ganttitle}

\begin{ganttitle} % Third title: Weeks
    \numtitle{6}{1}{29}{1}
    % start, skip, end, width       
\end{ganttitle}

%---------------------------------------
 \ganttmilestone{Task A}{0} % Milestone: Label, position
%---------------------------------------


%--------------------------------------- 
%   Task B
%---------------------------------------
\ganttgroup{Task B}{0}{6} % start, width 
%
\ganttbar[color=\defcolor,percent=.25]{Task B}{0}{1}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor,percent=.4]{Task B}{1}{1}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor,percent=.75]{Task B}{1}{4}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor,percent=.6]{Task B}{3}{3}
%
\ganttmilestonecon{Task B}{6}
%---------------------------------------


%--------------------------------------- 
%   Task C
%---------------------------------------
\ganttgroup{Task C}{6}{15} % start, width 
%
\ganttbar[color=\defcolor,percent=.8]{Task C}{6}{2}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor,percent=.75,percentpos=left]{Task C}{8}{8}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{15}{3}
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{16}{4}
%
\ganttmilestonecon{Task C}{20}
%
\ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor,percentpos=left]{Task C}{20}{1}
%
\ganttmilestonecon{Task C}{21}
%---------------------------------------
\end{gantt}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This fixed the dotted lines in the title, much appreciated!